# WF:can not get the parameters form the WorkflowStarted event

Tags: workflow-foundation

1. Thie is my code to create a workflowinstance;
2. I put a dictionary parameter for the CreateWorkflow methord;
3. But on the  WorkflowRuntime 's WorkflowStarted event, I can not get parameter from the callback event.

Like this:

```
this.workflowRuntime.WorkflowStarted += (o, e) => 
{ 
    //cant get dictionary  from the arguments
};

int deploymentId=100201;
Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

dictionary.Add("DeploymentId", deploymentId);
WorkflowInstance workflowInstance = workflowRuntime.CreateWorkflow(
    workflowDefinitionReader, rulesReader, dictionary);
workflowInstance.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check for is if the workflow itself defines the input argument `DeploymentId`. The name of the input argument in the XAML must be exactly as you specify in the dictionary.